# How to optimize Query for Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have more than 60k records, and I use Has() to get records by the relationship but it slow more than 5s with pagination and 2s for the query.

```
$products = Item::has('product_save');
```

my query :

```
select * from `products` where exists (select * from `product_saves` where `products`.`id` = `product_saves`.`product_id` and `user_id` = 2)
```

I use Item to do same condition and filter by where(). Like is product still active or no price between 5 and 88...

Any way to optimize it? I added an index in the table but is still slow.

Comment: Have you analyzed the query with `EXPLAIN`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest is to use [Laravel's database query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) instead of ORM and also select something like 1 instead of all (*) in your subquery. try this:

```
DB::table('products')
    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('product_saves')
            ->whereRaw('products.id = product_saves.product_id AND user_id = 2');
    })
->get();
```

Comment: The performance of `select 1` is identical to `select *`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html